# How can i find my current login status - facebook API android

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am using Facebook Login Button to integrate Facebook Login to my app.

1. When i press Facebook Login Button , it authenticates my Credentials and if successfully done , then change text to Log Out & Go inside my app.
2. Now when i use app and i go out of App and when i again come back to Login Screen. Here i see logout - As i authenticate myself before and i didn't logout.
3. So My question is how to differentiate when i am already logged in or my session is expired ?

Here is a code i am using:

```
LoginButton authButton;

authButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.authButton);
// set permission list, Don't forget to add email

authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info", "email"));

authButton.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {

            authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info",
                    "email"));
            System.out.println("Inside Call");
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                fbToken = session.getAccessToken();


                                }

                            }
                        });
```

.....................................

Thank you very much in advance.

Regards,
Rakesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the session using Session.getActiveSession() and then listen for session change event

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
    onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
}
```

And then check the session status:

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
   if (state.isOpened()) {
       Log.i("Logged", "Logged in...");
   }else if (state.isClosed()) {
       Log.i("Logged", "Logged out...");
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes..It works.. Do you have any idea how can i logout or clear session when session is active ??

Comment: Try using session.closeAndClearTokenInformation() to logout the session