# How to check Facebook login status in android application.?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

As i checked in previous answers they suggest to use Session to check the Facebook logon status, but that class got removed in new versions, any one can you help me out to resolve this.

[How can i find my current login status - facebook API android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855599/how-can-i-find-my-current-login-status-facebook-api-android)

Comment: you can use `LoginManager`

Comment: Thanks for replay, I got stuck with another thing, can i ask with you.?

Comment: Check this answer, it uses LoginManager : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29742846/4617458

Comment: check my answer below.

Comment: My requirement is display MY Facebook status(posts) in My android application, user no need to login my android application once they open my application they want see my Facebook status(posts), How to ac chive this, am able to get the posts from my Facebook,   my issue is how to get the details with out user login

Comment: Hay @rushankshah,  Is this understandable,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can check the `AccessToken` :

```
 AccessToken token;
 token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

  if (token == null) {
   //Means user is not logged in
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get it from session

```
  public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        return (session != null && session.isOpened());
    }
```

source : [Facebook Login status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402775/android-facebook-sdk-check-if-the-user-is-logged-in-or-not)